Каким образом реализована индексация элементов в массивах в c#?
Недавно узнал о такой разновидности коллекции, как очередь (стек) на связных списках, а также о том, как сделать такую коллекцию перечисляемой в цикле foreach.
Естественно, сразу возник вопрос - а как же реализовать в такой коллекции индексацию элементов? Как ни ломал голову, но без использования уже существующих коллекций ничего не придумывается.
Но ведь как-то в самой основной коллекции в C# это реализовано (на сколько я понимаю, основной коллекцией является массив). Chat GPT и Gemini тоже ничего внятного по этому поводу не ответили.
Просветите, пожалуйста, кто знает - как в c# реализована индексация массивов? Заранее спасибо!

Так массив - это сплошной кусок памяти, в котором хранятся указатели на объекты (если они reference type), либо сами объекты (если они value type). Подряд хранятся. Поэтому достаточно знать адрес начала массива, размер типа элементов массива и индекс, чтобы сразу спозиционироваться в нужное место памяти: адрес = начало_массива + индекс * размер_элемента..

Хмммм... Да, вариант. В это мне, пожалуй, пока рановато лезть...)) Как же тогда индексацию впихнуть в свою коллекцию? Единственное, до чего смог додуматься - это сделать дополнительный класс, хранящий в полях некоторое фиксированное количество ссылок на объекты коллекции (например, кратное 10), а также ссылки на свои копии. Разделив индекс на 10 можно будет сразу понять, где он лежит. Но как-то это всё громоздко и сложно получается...)

Индексация массивов отличается от индексации любой другой коллекции, так как массив - это единственная нативная коллекция.
Обращение к элементу массива по индексу, это получение данных из ячейки памяти по смещению от начала массива, равному размеру одного элемента массива, умноженному на индекс. Именно поэтому индексация в массивах начинается с 0, потому что по формуле адрес первого элемента совпадает с началом массива.
Что касается остальных коллекций, то не следует путать перечисляемость и индекс. Коллекция может не содержать индекса, но являться перечисляемой (реализует интерфейс IEnumerable<T>), и наоборот, некий объект может содержать индексатор (T1 this[T2], но не являться перечисляемым.
Вот пример перечисляемой коллекции, которая вовсе не коллекция, а простой перечислитель.
public class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

Вот так пользоваться
MyEnumerable enumerable = new();
foreach (var item in enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Вывод в консоль
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Вот пример объекта с индексатором
public class MyIndex
{
    public int this[int i]
    {
        get { return i * 2; }
    }
}

Оно просто возвращает удвоенный индекс
MyIndex index = new();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index[i]);
}

Вывод в консоль
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18

Как вы поняли, чтобы сделать что-то перечисляемое или индексируемое (или и то и другое одновременно), совсем необязательно какие-то данные в реальной коллекции хранить. А как я выше сказал - единственная нативная коллекция в .NET это массив.
Тот же список List<T> работает на базе массива - вот его исходный код.
UPD: Про индексаторы почитать можно здесь или в документации.

Благодарю за ответ! Про индексатор можно чуть подробнее, или хотя бы наводку где почитать? Не совсем понял, как работает данный индексатор. С виду обычное свойство, только вот "this" немного смущает...)) Про интерфейс IEnumerable для перечисляемости я в курсе, в вопросе как раз и написал об этом.

@JamesBond ну я ссылку на исходники списка кинул, посмотрите как пример. Почитать можно здесь или в документации. Индексатор синтаксически похож на обычное свойство с геттером и сеттером.

Благодарю! Сейчас изучим)

В определении абстрактного типа данных "стек" есть только две обязательных операции: push и pop. Это указано в английской вики: Stack (abstract data type). В русском варианте это явно не описано.
Взятие элемента по индексу в общем случае невозможно для стека.
Если сделать конкретную реализацию стека на массиве, то можно добавить индексацию. Но если реализация сделана, как у вас, на связном списке, то индекс не имеет смысла.

Добавлю, что абстрактный тип данных "очередь" тоже не имеет обязательного требования индексации, а лишь операции, чаще всего называемые enqueue и dequeue.

Меня интересует не столько целесообразность внедрения в стек индексации, сколько варианты ее реализации. Я пока не имею представления о том, как это делается, поэтому и задал вопрос, а пример со стеком и очередью привел просто для того, чтобы было ясно почему такие вопросы появились.

Вы наверное поняли что в связных списках хранятся не сами объекты а врапперы с вашими объектами.
Ну как вариант храните в ваших враппер обьектах дополнительные свойства (index, prev, ...). Беда только придется переинтексировать после вставки во связный список.

Спасибо за ответ! Хранить в объектах коллекции их индексы - это самом собой разумеющаяся идея (хотя и необязательная). Важно-то не чтобы у объекта был номер, а чтобы к этому объекту можно было получить доступ по его номеру. А для этого список номеров нужно хранить где-то в классе самой коллекции. Также нужно помнить, что стеки и очереди - коллекции потенциально неограниченного размера. Вот мне и интересно, как это можно сделать не используя существующие коллекции. Как-то же в массиве это сделали?
